# Xamarin.Forms: how to "center" vertically a label on itself for Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, label, vertical-alignment

I try to use a **FontIcon** to show an item through a **customized Label**.

As the icon is wider than it is tall, I would like to adjust the **height** and the **vertical alignement**.

However, I encounter a strange behavior on Android, whereas it works fine on iOS.

For example, with a default Label and a basic text the result is the same:

```
<Grid HeightRequest="80">
    <Label Text="A" TextColor="Black" 
           FontSize="150" 
           BackgroundColor="Yellow"
           VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

As I explained, it works fine on iOS,

[image: iOS]

But not on Android:

[image: Android]

***Would you have any explanation or any suggestion?***

I've tested another approach by adding a negative margin on Android:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="Olive"
      HeightRequest="120">
    <Label Text="A" TextColor="Black" 
           FontSize="180" 
           BackgroundColor="Yellow"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalTextAlignment="Start">
        <Label.Margin>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                <On Platform="Android" Value="0, -70, 0, 0" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </Label.Margin>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

The results looks good, on iOS:

[image: iOS2]

And it seems to be good on Android too:

[image: Android2]

But this works only for some devices, the rendering is not always the same when I test this on real devices or different emulators...

***I'm not that it's the better approach, but I'm not sure that I can achieve this.***

Comment: Your Grid has VerticalOptions="Start" and your Label has VerticalOptions="Center". I can't test your code to give you an actual answer, but is there a reason this is so? Have you tried taking the VerticalOptions out of either the Label or the Grid and see what happens?

Comment: You're right, I can change these values but this doesn't change anything. In add, if I remove the Grid and set the HeightRequest directly on the Label, I still get the same result...

Comment: Hi @JakenHerman have you been able to test this from your side?